# Rails SimpleForm with nested models: submission redirects to parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I have a `User` that `has_many :recipes`. I'm using `simple_form`, and trying to use a form to create a new recipe. Simple, right? I've looked through a dozen SO questions, and I thought I had fixed all the gotchas, including `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and everything.

Now, when I submit the form to create a new recipe, it redirects me to the user edit form with errors about the user. Here's the relevant code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible ..., :recipes_attributes

  has_many :recipes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes
end


class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user

end
```

And `recipes/new.html.haml`

```
= simple_nested_form_for @user do |f|

  = f.simple_fields_for :recipes, @user.recipes do |rf|
    = rf.input :name
    = rf.input :source
    = rf.input :link
    = rf.input :season, collection: %w(spring summer fall winter), prompt: 'Choose season', required: false
    = rf.input :protein, as: :radio_buttons, required: false
    = rf.input :course, collection: ['appeteizer', 'soup', 'dessert', 'entrée', 'side', 'salad'], prompt: 'Choose course', required: false
    = rf.input :featured, as: :boolean, required: false
    = rf.input :directions, as: :text
    .actions
      = f.submit 'Save'
      or
      = link_to 'Cancel', user_recipes_path(@user)
```

I also tried  `= f.simple_fields_for :recipe do |rf|`

And here's the `new` method of `RecipesController`

```
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @recipe = @user.recipes.build || @recipe.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @recipe }
    end
  end
```

It looks like it's trying to post to the users controller instead of the recipes controller, which explains why it redirects me to editing a user. Here's the log of the put request:

```
Started PUT "/users/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-19 22:31:07 -0700
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QmCo025nqR9vJt49To1gQ7/edv4MSlvuwHYotEihI2E=", "user"=>{"recipes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"dffd", "source"=>"dfswer", "link"=>"ewrre", "season"=>"", "course"=>"", "featured"=>"0", "directions"=>"werew"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"4"}
```

I know it is technically a `form_for @user`, but since it's creating a recipe, how would I make that put go to `recipes` to create a new recipe? And do I want it to put `recipes_attributes`, or `recipe_attributes`? It's for a new recipe, and I tried getting it to accept nested attributes for recipe or recipes (I made the forms match accordingly). I guess I'm confused about that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a form for User `simple_nested_form_for @user` . Thats why the form gets submitted to users_controller.

If you dont have any user related fields in the form, create a form for recipes

```
form_for([@user, @recipe]) do
```

Comment: I had tried that, but the recipes weren't getting submitted with a user_id. Do I just add that as a hidden field?

Comment: Updated my answer. This will submit the form with the user id.